# Is it possible to show satisfied validation rule in different colour using jquery validation engine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am using multiple conditions for validating a field in my form using jquery validation engine. I want to show the user if a condition is satisfied with a green background colour. currently my validation looks like this:

[image]

Now when the first condition is satisfied, The background colour of first line should turn green.But it is disappearing now. Is that possible using jquery validation engin js?

I want something like this:
[image]

Comment: Please be more mindful when tagging.  jQuery Validate plugin is not the same as the jQuery Validation Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. on Success event validator engine will add "`valid`" class to the input. So, using `valid` class you can do your styling.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/kyK4G/358/

```
input.valid { border: 1px solid green; background: green; }
```

Comment: I dont want to turn the text box to green. I want to show the popup  message box in green.

Comment: The OP asked about the "jQuery Validation Engine" and your jsFiddle is using the jQuery Validate plugin... something else entirely.